# Is it possible to fire Click event on button through eye tracker?

Tags: android, opencv, eye-tracking, eye-detection

my requirements are 3 icons per screen and eye tracking to select icons.Example: for user 1, if the eye is tracked on the icon for 3 sec, then it is selected and proceed to the next screen.as per my idea eye tracking is possible through OpenCv but how can i manage click event for icons.

Comment: Eye tracking is possible; but I think that you want to detect where the eye is looking at. It is something different, and harder to implement. And for icons, you need to use OpenCVSharp, GTK+ or Qt as opencv highgui offers ilmited interface and event handling.

Comment: Tnx so much Canberk for comment, if it's possible can you please provide me a reference links or example links this implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for [eye detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). You need to somehow apply a post processing step to detect where it is looking. [OpenCvSharp](https://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/) is a C# wrapper for opencv library, which is actually written in C/C++. Work on C# as its the best for your purpose. Note that latest opencvsharp stable (2.4.5) uses 2.4.0 dlls of opencv. Use a pixel value to activate a button as a starting point. Then use pixel = eye tracker output. Good luck.